# Restrict the jqWidgets Combo Box to Value List

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, autocomplete, widget

I'm developing a web app and I want a combo box with a list of potential values.

Here's some behavior that I want:

1. I want it to have an arrow on the right that you can click, and you get a drop-down of the different options.
2. I want it to have a text field where you can type.
3. I want it to autocomplete for you, so it narrows the list of options as you type.
4. I want it to select the closest option if you cut off in the middle of typing.
5. I want it to lock to just the list of options, so that no random values can be sent.

This seems like pretty normal behavior for a widget; I feel like I've seen this in a variety of places--but always incomplete.

I finally came to two options: [jQuery UI's Autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) (extensively modified) or [jqWidgets' Combo Box](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxcombobox/index.htm?%28arctic%29).

The jQuery UI solution seemed like it would require a lot of work, and I liked the look/style of the jqWidgets one better, so I went with that--only to discover that you could not lock the submitted value to the list that you provide.  If you select from the drop-down, you get a proper value, but if you type in text it can be whatever you want.

Surely there must be a way, some setting or another, to make the widget lock to the list of values!  Nope.  I found a thread on the jqWidgets forum where one of the team members says as much:

http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/combobox-with-autocomplete-and-selectable-only-from-the-list/

Now, it's possible that there's some officially-sanctioned way to do it, that this guy didn't know, that I just haven't found, but...I haven't found it.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`comboBox.jqxComboBox({selectionMode: "dropDownList"});` could be helpful as well.

Comment: That is not an option in their API per the official site, here: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxcombobox/index.htm?(arctic)#demos/jqxcombobox/defaultfunctionality.htm  Care to explain?

Comment: if you wish, try it. It's your choice.

Comment: Fascinating.  That setting is nowhere in their API at all, or in any of their examples that I can see, but when I beautify the JS file and search through it, I do see that setting and the behavior associated with it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So after a number of grueling hours, I made a JS hack that does the trick:

```
function lockComboBox ($aComboBox, aNullLabel) {

    // TODO: Add the ability to not have a null option...?

    // Set nullOption if it's not.
    if (aNullLabel == null || aNullLabel == '') {
        aNullLabel = 'None'; 
    }

    $aComboBox.jqxComboBox('insertAt', { label: aNullLabel, value: ''}, 0);
    $aComboBox.jqxComboBox({autoComplete: true }); 

    $aComboBox.on('focusout', function (eventargs) {
        var $this = $(this);

        // Items are all items, visible items is the set after filtering during autocompletion.
        var items = $this.jqxComboBox('getItems');
        var vItems = $this.jqxComboBox('getVisibleItems');

        // Function to check for 'None' and null out the value if found.
        // Necessary because the combo box will stick the label as the value if the value is null.
        function nullFix (nameAttrib) {
            if ($this.jqxComboBox('val') == aNullLabel) {
                $this.find("input[name^='"+nameAttrib+"']").val('');
                return;
            }
        }

        // Next check to see if the value is 'None'
        var valueMember = $this.jqxComboBox('valueMember');
        nullFix(valueMember);

        // Next check to see if the value is an exact match to one of our items                 
        var valueMember = $this.jqxComboBox('valueMember');
        var value = $this.find("input[name^='"+valueMember+"']").attr("value");  
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (value == items[i].value) {
                $this.jqxComboBox('close');
                $this.jqxComboBox('selectIndex', items[i].index);
                return;
            }
        }

        // Next see if the visible items are less than the total
        if (vItems.length < items.length && vItems.length > 0) {

            // If that's the case, it's been filtered, so take the closest one.
            $this.jqxComboBox('close');
            $this.jqxComboBox('selectItem', vItems[0]);

            // Perform another nullcheck
            nullFix(valueMember);

        } else {

            // Otherwise, clear the selection 
            $this.jqxComboBox('close');
            $this.jqxComboBox('clearSelection');

        }
    });

}
```

That does the trick.  Make your combo box and then call the function on it, like so:

```
// Create a jqxComboBox with the data adapter
$comboBox.jqxComboBox({ source: myAdapter, displayMember: "displayLabels", valueMember: "actualValues", width: 200, height: 25 });
// Lock the combo box to its own values, with null option 'None'
lockComboBox ($comboBox, 'None');
```

It seems to correctly handle the different things that can occur: the box losing focus, or the user selecting from the drop-down, etc.  Without a "None" item, there was one behavior quirk that I couldn't fix (it could be difficult to clear out the box) so I added that in.  I may need to add something later so that you can lock it to the values, but without a null option.

I hope this is useful to someone down the road.  :)

Edit:

This actually has something broken about it; it seems to work the first time when you pick something, but if you focus/blur the field again, it blanks it for some reason.  I won't be fixing this because there's a simpler solution in the now-accepted answer.